# Component name in angular 2+

Tags: angular, components, angular-cli

When we execute `ng g c componentname` then it generate files with suffix `. component.ts`. For instance :

`ng g c suruchi` will create files `suruchi.component.ts` i want generated component files name to be only suruchi.ts

Kindly suggest any provision.

Comment: try this `ng generate class suruchi`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng g c suruchi --type=
```

Comment: Hey, you should add details to why this would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is  no  cli command for generate component without .component  suffix. So  you  have to  create files manually and then add the reference in the  module file.